# Antd V4 form list setFieldValue

Tags: reactjs, antd

enter code hereHow can we dynamically edit an element in form list and set that element using setFieldsValue

A solution I got is call setFieldsValue for entire form List but that is not fair, cause performance issue

I have a form structure like this

```
users: [
  {
    name: "bob",
    education: [
      {
        qualification: "masters",
        college: "abc",
      },
      {
        qualification: "degree",
        collge: "ijk",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "alice",
    education: [
      {
        qualification: "ug",
        college: "abc",
      },
      {
        qualification: "higher secondary",
        college: "def",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

implemented using form list

- I want to update 'qualification' of  'education[1]' of user 'alice'
  using antd v4 setFieldsValue
- I got a solution that is, take all values using getFieldsValue and
  change change 'qualification' and then update entire form value, but
  it causes some performance issue large applications
- How to use setFieldsValue to update a single field in form?
- In antd v3 it is archived by providing path in setFeildsValue like

  setFieldsValue({    'user.1.education.1.qualification':'something' })

Thanks in advance for your valuable answers

Comment: Can you share a example code of what you already acheived?

Comment: updated with a simple example

Comment: @AjishVNair Did you ever find a way to do this? Seems like it'd be a very useful thing, but the Ant docs are still not quite as detailed as I'd like re: setFieldsValue.

Comment: use setFields([{name:[],value:''}])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you didn't understand @Ajish answer (like me), I'll try to explain it:

As [Antd docs](https://ant.design/components/form/#FieldData) says, you need to pass a `FieldData[]` to your `form.setFields()` method. In my case, I need to update only one field and I only used `name` and `value` properties from FieldData. Therefore, my code was like this:

```
form.setFields([
  {
    name: ['products', fieldIndex, 'total-value'],
    value: totalValue,
  },
]);
```

`Name` property is a [NamePath](https://ant.design/components/form/#NamePath) composed by:

- 'products': Name of my `Form.List` component;
- fieldIndex: Index refering the object that I want to update;
- 'total-value': Field that I want to update.

To clarify even more, `products` has this format:

```
products: [
  {
    quantity: 0,
    'unit-value': 0,
    'total-value': 0,
   },
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setFields([{name:[data[0].name[0], data[0].name[1], 'component_pm'],value:5}])
```

Comment: This answer is correct, just poorly formatted. Maybe you can update it @Ajish and explain further what the different components are? E.g. the key is that you specify name as an array of `[<Form.List group name>, <index>, <field name>]`.

Comment: `setFields` is a function in the `Form` instance - [docs](https://ant.design/components/form/#FormInstance)