# How to change the value of a dynamic form field in antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a dynamic form in antd. I want to change another field's value based on the value of another field. I am using `onFieldsChange` to detect the required change and then trying to change the value of another field equal to the currently changed value.

```
const handleFieldsChange = (data) => {
    // console.log(data);

    if (data)
      if (data[0])
        if (data[0].name)
          if (data[0].name[2]) {
            if (data[0].name[2] === 'quantity') {
              // console.log(data[0].value);
              // form.setFieldsValue()
              form.setFieldsValue({
                [[data[0].name[0], data[0].name[1], 'component_pm']]: 5,
              });
            }
            // if (data[0].name[2] === 'kit') {
            // }
          }
  };
```

I want to put the quantity value in the component_pm field.

The form :
[image]

Comment: Can you share your entire component code? It may be more correct to use an effect to updated form fields in response to *some* form state values changing but we don't know if you are using controlled/uncontrolled inputs, etc... we need more details.

Comment: @DrewReese The inputs are not controlled. I am not using ```onChange``` to set the values using local state. I was about to try that. How will I change the same dynamic row's ```component_pm``` value using the onChange function.

Comment: I am also facing same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62393532/antd-v4-form-list-setfieldvalue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use setFeilds

```
setFields([{name:[data[0].name[0], data[0].name[1], 'component_pm'],value:5}])
```

Comment: `setFields` is a function in the `Form` instance - [docs](https://ant.design/components/form/#FormInstance)

Comment: @ajish-v-nair what if i m using dynamic form and using onChange with <Select /> how can i manipulate data then?